# Equal operator cannot be applied between primitive and boxed variable

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin it is trivial to compare some Long value to 0 like this.

```
if (firstUnread == 0) {
    return
}
```

But usually this error occurs. What is the best way to compare these values?

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'Long' and 'Int'

Comment: change 0 to 0L (at least try that, I'm not very familiar with Kotlin and it's not clear from your question which language is giving you the error)

Comment: It's Kotlin (in Java, it would be either `long` and `int`, or `Long` and `Integer`).

Comment: @PaulHicks got it... before you changed the image to text, I couldn't tell whether it was saying `Int` or `int`--resolution wasn't good enough.

Comment: It might be nice to be able to create an extension equals() method for Int, but it would shadow the member equals() so it won't work. Have to cast when used.

Answer (score 3):

0 is an `Int` in Kotlin.
try to replace it with `0L` instead and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, there are no implicit widening conversions for numbers: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html

In your code you are attempting to compare a `Long` (`firstUnread`) to an `Int` (`0`). Instead compare to `0L` so you are comparing a `Long` to a `Long.`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add `.toLong()` method after any int number.
Just change your code to this:

```
if (firstUnread == 0.toLong()) {
    return
}
```

Comment: rather use `0L` instead of the more complicated `0.toLong()`